# Handle replication lag in data pipeline

Tags: postgresql, celery, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, system-design

Given a pipeline of tasks that run in sequence. Each task consumes data from the database, manipulate it, and produces (write) to the same database.

We are using AWS RDS Aurora, and in order to spread the load, the “reading phase” of each task is done within the read replica.
In some cases of high loads, we reach replication lag of 10-15 seconds. This means that by the time the new task consume data, it gets wrong/missing data points.

We know this is not the “right” way to design such pipeline, and it contradicts the idiom “Do not communicate by sharing memory; instead, share memory by communicating”.
Since it’s too much effort to change the design now, we come up with alternative solution:

Create a service that check replication lag value and expose it to all tasks. If the value is greater than x, task will fallback to read from RDS master node.

This is not optimal, and I would like to hear other solution to bypass this issue.

It is worth mentioning that we are using Celery (& Python) to construct such workflow and each task is unaware of the tasks that ran previously.

Answer (score 0):

There will always be data which is inserted into the database but not yet visible, either because it wasn't committed yet, it was committed after your snapshot was started, or due to replication lag.  The only real solution is to make your tasks robust to this inevitability.

> Create a service that check replication lag value and expose it to all tasks. If the value is greater than x, task will fallback to read from RDS master node.

You want to shed load from the master until the first sign of trouble, then you want to suddenly dump all the load back onto it?

Comment: When task A finishes it will defiantly have the data committed to the master node. The issue is that on rare occasions task B starts and loads data from the replica that was not yet ready. If task B was reading from the master node there was no issue. A suggested solution is when task B wants to read data it first query the replication lag, if it is higher than the thresholds than is will read from the master node, otherwise it is ok to read from the replica.

Answer (score 0):

> Create a service that check replication lag value and expose it to all tasks. If the value is greater than x, task will fallback to read from RDS master node

Depending on the cause of your replication lag this might make things worse due to further increasing the load on the master node.

If your pipeline allows it you could wait in Task A, after write, until the data propagated to the read replica.